# Error in 'Master Database Restore' in SQL Server 2012 (Because of difference in SQL Server Build)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a backup of a `master` database that was taken from SQL Server 2012 11.00.2218 build.

Now I have a new SQL Server installation with build 11.00.2100. I tried restoring the master database after running in single-use mode but got the error as follows:

> The backup of the system database on the device E:\master_backup.bak cannot be restored because it was created by a different version of the server (11.00.2218) than this server (11.00.2100).

I also tried installing SQL Server 2012 SP2. But still the same error. Please help

Comment: [Link to Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264474/en-us) regarding this issue.

Comment: That applies to SQL Server 2000, 2005. Even though i have tried it. Its not working

Comment: If you run `SELECT @@VERSION` on the target server what does it return.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your destination server to build 11.00.2218 before restoring the backup of master, that's your only chance.

If you can't do that (say, the destination master is corrupted, which is why you are trying to do this restore), then [rebuild the master via this method](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003.aspx) so you can get the instance up, then apply the upgrade, then restore master.